# JS - How to add three inputs, get the text from them and show the text in another subpage

Tags: javascript, html, text, input

I have a problem with adding three input text fields after I put one button. 
I'd like to have three new input fields after i push the button "Add author" - these inputs would be: 1. name 2. surname 3. initial. Everyone new input needs to have a different id in order to take the text from the inputs and show it in the new subpage which has to show up right after I push the button "Make the order".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang='en'> 
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = Load;

function Load()

{

document.getElementById('add_input').onclick = AddElement;

}

function AddElement()

{

var element = document.createElement('input');
var element2 = document.createElement('input');
var element3 = document.createElement('input');

element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
element.setAttribute('type', 'text');
var number = 0;
var amount = document.forms['add_file'].elements.length;
for (var i = 0; i < ilosc; i++ )
{
if (document.forms['add_file'].elements[i].type == 'text')
{
number += 1;
}

}
element.setAttribute('name', 'file-'+(liczba+1));
element.setAttribute('nazwisko', 'file-'+(liczba+1));
element.style.display = "block";
element.style.margin= "2px";
document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(element);
}
</script>


<!--making order -->

<script>

function getText(){

var publisher = document.getElementById("publisher");
var year = document.getElementById("year"); 
var div = document.getElementById("readyorder")
div.innerHTML = "("+surname.value+" "+year.value+","+" "+"s."+" "+page.value+")";

}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class='container'>

<!-- header --> 
<header>
<img src="images/header.jpg" alt=""/>
</header>


<input type="text" name="file-1" />
<input type="text" name="surname-1" />
<input type="submit" value="Add author" id="add_input" />

<form name="add_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
</form>


Author's Surname<br>
<input type="text" id="surname"><br>
Page number<br>
<input type="text" id="page"><br>
Year<br>
<input type="text" id="year"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Make the order" onclick="getText()" /> <br/><br/>


<div id="readyorder"></div><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is ```AddElement()``` getting called? Any errors in your console?

Comment: Also, I am not sure you are appending your child elements in the for loop.

Comment: I can't see any

Comment: Well, how it would look like?

Comment: Sorry @lookasz, I'm a bit confused by what you are trying to do, might have to explain it better

Comment: Ok, so when I push the button "Add Author" it makes only one input text field - I would like to have three new input fields every time I push "Add Author.
The next thing - I need to put all information together from all inputs and show them on the next new webpage in certain order - so far it shows the text from severak the inputs in div "readyorder”.

Comment: You might need to go back and learn a few javascript basics. You are only appending ```element``` to the form, not ```element2``` and ```element3```.

Comment: Yup, I am still learning javascript, how would you append element2 and element3 to the form?

Comment: Is anybody willing to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Store your `id` globaly and increase on each addition.

While Creating your `node` set their `id` value using `setAttribute`

```
element1.setAttribute('id', 'surname' + number);
```

Also Create a `button` while adding `textbox's` which let you know current order.

```
var button = document.createElement('input');
```

Add `onclick` attribute to call `javascript function`

```
button.setAttribute('onclick', 'getText(' + number + ')');
```

```js
window.onload = Load;
var number = 0;

function Load()
{
 document.getElementById('add_input').onclick = AddElement;
}

function AddElement()
{
 var element1 = document.createElement('input');
 var element2 = document.createElement('input');
 var element3 = document.createElement('input');
 var label1 = document.createElement('label');
 var label2 = document.createElement('label');
 var label3 = document.createElement('label');
 var button = document.createElement('input');
 
 label1.innerHTML = "</br>Author's Surname " + number + "</br>";

 element1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
 element1.setAttribute('id', 'surname' + number);
 element1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Surname...');
 label1.appendChild(element1);
 
 label2.innerHTML = '</br>Page number ' + number + '</br>';

 element2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
 element2.setAttribute('id', 'page' + number);
 element2.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Page...');
 label2.appendChild(element2);

 label3.innerHTML = '</br>Year ' + number + '</br>';

 element3.setAttribute('type', 'text');
 element3.setAttribute('id', 'year' + number);
 element3.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Year...');
 label3.appendChild(element3);
 
 button.setAttribute('onclick', 'getText(' + number + ')');
 button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
 button.setAttribute('value', 'Button ' + number);
 
 document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label1);
 document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label2);
 document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(label3);
 document.forms['add_file'].appendChild(button);
 number++;
}

function getText(id)
{
 var surname = document.getElementById("surname" + id);
 var page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
 var year = document.getElementById("year" + id);
 var div = document.getElementById("readyorder")
 div.innerHTML = "("+surname.value+" "+year.value+","+" "+"s."+" "+page.value+")";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="file-1" />
<input type="text" name="surname-1" />
<input type="submit" value="Add author" id="add_input" />

<form name="add_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
</form>

<hr>

<div id="readyorder"></div><br/>
```